# How to run jslint on the client?

Tags: javascript, jslint

For testing purposes, obviously not for production.  What is the best way to do this?

Googling I found this [tutorial](http://af-design.com/blog/2011/01/04/automating-jslint-validation/), and of course the project on [github](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint).

For starters which files do I need to run:

```
// removed
```

and is there an API reference.  I see there is a large comment block in jslint.js that seems to server this purpose but was wondering if there is something easier to read.

Because the client has no file access, I was planning on ajaxing the code in to get its contents.

**Please** never the mind, on why I want to do this on the client.

Comment: Why run it on the client? You're linting source code. Do it in your IDE or in your build time test suite (which is what the tutorial you found does).

Comment: @mark_huffington: Is it top secret?

Comment: When people want to solve a problem in a crazy way instead of one of the normal ways, it is natural to question why. That way they can learn to use one of the sane ways, or given an explanation as to why the crazy way is needed that will encourage people to help.

Comment: you box headed thinking fools, I will crush you on the polo field.

Comment: I'm also minifying from the client via Google Closure API, how you like them apples!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you include the JSLint script you will have access to a single global variable, `JSLINT`. You can invoke it with a string and an optional map of options:

```
var valid = JSLINT(code, options);
```

The result will be `true` or `false`, depending on whether the code passed the check based on the provided options.

After this call you can inspect the `JSLINT.errors` property for an array of warnings, if any.

This is precisely what I have done to build JSLint integration into the editor in the articles on http://jslinterrors.com.

Comment: you sir are a scholar and a compatriot, we will fight the evil together!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at http://jshint.com/ ?  Source is available here: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/

The browser bundle is available here: http://jshint.com/get/jshint-2.1.10.js and the docs describe how to call it (http://jshint.com/docs/)